# Explicit Call to FormExtensions.BeginForm resolves HttpGet-decorated method instead of HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm following a pattern which I've used MANY times in my current project, yet for the most recent view I've written, BeginForm() is resolving the GET route for my action method, rather than the POST.  I have no idea what I've done differently, so I'm really stumped.  Example code below:

```
public class FooController:Controller {
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Bar(int id) {
    return View(new Model(id));
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Bar(Model model) {
    //do stuff with the model
  }
}

//Bar View
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formName').submit(function() {
      if(/* invalid input */) {
        //set html for an error div
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
@model Model
@using(Html.BeginForm("Bar",           //action name
                      "Foo",           //controller name
                      null,            //explicit null for route values
                      FormMethod.Post  //explicitly set form method
                      new {id="formName"})){  //explicitly id the form
  //bunch of inputs, a la
  @Html.TextBox("Property", Model.Property)
}

//Bar html
<form id="formName" action="/Foo/Bar/{Model Id}" method="post">
  <!-- input elements, etc -->
</form>
```

Every overload of BeginForm which I've tried has resolved the route with the Id following the action, so that every time the form POSTs to the GET method.

I tried renaming the POST method to, e.g., "BarBar", and updating the call to BeginForm - in that case, the route resolved correctly and the form POSTed to the appropriate action.

I've followed this pattern for dozens of other forms - anyone know what I may have done wrong this time?

Comment: This looks fine. There's probably something else to the picture or this is not your actual code.

Comment: I have a <script> block for input validation immediately preceding the @BeginForm area.  I'll update the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

For the inputs are you using Html.TextBoxFOR, Html.DropDownListFOR etc instead of just Html.TextBox?

Comment: No, just calling @Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name)

Comment: Ok so try Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) this should bind it to the name property of the model.

Comment: Model binding has not been a problem.  The POST action works fine when I give it a different name - the model is initialized with all the proper values.  The issue here is that BeginForm is constructing the wrong route for the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking outside the box here, but what happens if you use the following instead.  Neither of your actions explicitly takes zero parameters, so I'm wondering if the routing engine is having a tough time picking the "correct" path:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Bar",          
                      "Foo",          
                      new {model = null},
                      FormMethod.Post,
                      new {id="formName"}))
```

Comment: And yes, I agree it should be "smart enough" to pick the action decorated with [HttpPost] when you explicitly use FormMethod.Post in your call to BeginForm.

Comment: new {model = null} results in a syntax error; apparently you can't assign 'null' to an anonymous property.